# is this algorithm right for checking a terminating decimal?

Tags: decimal

```
int is_ter(int x)
{
    //it is not a TWOs nor a FIVEs and not 1.0
g:  
    if(x%2 !=0 && x%5 !=0 && x!=1 )
        return 0;
    // make sure it is 1.0
    if(x%2 !=0 && x%5 !=0 && x==1 )
        return 1;
    //check if it is a two
    if(x%2==0){
         x/=2;
         goto g;
    }
    if(x%5==0)
    {
        x/=5;
        goto g;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's a 'terminating decimal'? Why are you using `goto`? You have an inifite loop if x=0, for example. And negatives will wreak havoc, too.

Comment: a decimal that doesnt have a repeating period
1/5 is terminating because it == 0.2
while 1/6 and 1/7 are not 
and regarding the input x is always > 0

Answer (score 5):

From the looks of it, you want to check whether 1/x is terminating or not.

Your code looks somewhat confusing. You'll want to check whether all your primefactors are 2 or 5:

```
int is_ter(unsigned int x)
{
    while (x>1)
    {
       if (x%2==0) x=x/2;
       else if (x%5==0) x=x/5;
       else return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

should do the trick (ok, it says 1/0 is terminating, whatever that means. It's going to terminate the program, so it's not exactly wrong...)

Comment: yea i forgot to mention that input x is >0
nevertheless I used ur code instead .. and I got the same result ..

Answer (score 1):

No, not at all.

First of all, your decimal is an int. Second, you should probably be multiplying instead of dividing. Third, when working with decimals, rounding errors occur all the time, so you need to take that into account when comparing decimals to something.

And most importantly, *all* decimals stored on a computer are 'terminating', because in a computer, a decimal fraction is not much more than a rational number M/N, with N being a power of 2.

You should do some reading about [floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

Comment: well let me explain this more
I have a fraction a/b
and am ONLY sending b to this function
so if we have 5984845495/32
we know that this fraction is terminating (not repeating with a continuous period )..
so am not checking a decimal itself ,, that is so unresonable.

Comment: That's a different question. You need to see if b has a prime-factor that isn't 2 or 5. So divide by 2 until you can't anymore, then divide by 5 until you can't anymore. Your code tries to do something like this, but doesn't really do that.